# Loader image hidden-visibility effect using javascript and CSS

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

In the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AmHSC/

```
    <img src="http://www.laneaviation.com/wp-content/themes/laneaviation/images/loading.gif" id="loader" />
    var loader = document.getElementById('loader');
```

I want this image to be hidden by javascript.
The idea is to show the image and as soon as my program return false the image is hidden, showing a loading effect to the user.

Answer (score 1):

`loader.style.display = 'none';`

Comment: Actually it works, but in if-else statement 
when I return it like
return loader.style.display = 'none';
I don't see it working ?

Answer (score 1):

```
loader.style.display = "none"; // <-- You can use style method to style any element
```